# После того когда создал Рабочую версию приложения в Google Play Console нужно или нет Отключать бета-тестирование? (Там есть такой пункт)

Tags: android, google-play

Если не отключать Бета-тестирование, что будет?

Comment: https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/7003180?hl=ru
справка может помочь понять

Answer (score 1):

Никакого вреда и пользы на своих приложениях не наблюдается.
Если рабочая версия имеет Version Code выше чем бета-версия, то она не будет распространяться. Это в том случае если вы выложили новую версию не в бета, а в рабочую.
Если же перевели из беты в рабочую - то тут вроде всё понятно, она станет рабочей и бета версия как таковая будет совпадать с рабочей.

Comment: Что значит будет совпадать с рабочей? Она останется доступной? Или ее надо физически удалить, чтобы ее никто больше не видел?

Comment: Так будет написано в консоли Google Play. По факту - это означает что она не действительна. Удалять ничего не надо. Вообще в существует два вида тестирования - закрытое и открытое. Закрытое - только по приглашениям, открытое - по ссылке, но некоторым активным пользователям Гугл предлагает вступить в программу тестирования, но это только если есть бета версия, если бета заменена на рабочую, то поставится в любом случае - последняя.